# Remove outlier for data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
clean_data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [3, 11, 3], [7,8,12]])
```

I have this df, I want to iterate though each row and find element which is bigger than 10 and replace it with mean value of that row. I can do it with ugly code but I believe there are ways to do it with a few lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `mean`:

```
df = clean_data.mask(clean_data > 10, clean_data.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
   0         1  2
0  1  2.000000  3
1  3  5.666667  3
2  7  8.000000  9
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(clean_data > 10, clean_data.mean(axis=1), clean_data), 
                  columns=clean_data.columns,
                  index=clean_data.index)
print (df)
     0         1    2
0  1.0  2.000000  3.0
1  3.0  5.666667  3.0
2  7.0  8.000000  9.0
```